# How to run the same recent file in IDLE without switching to the file itself [workflow]?

Tags: python, python-idle, coding-efficiency

To run a file in IDLE I press F6, then I see the results in the IDLE shell.
I want to enhance my workflow a bit.
I want to run the same command **from inside the IDLE** without editing the file, then pressing F6 again from the active file window.
Ideally:

- edit file
- press button in IDLE
- IDLE runs the newly saved version itself
- no need to switch and press F6 in the file window

The file here:
[image: the file]

The IDLE shell here:
[image: kk]

Comment: Are you bound to using IDLE? There are other editors out there. Otherwise I would just start a terminal, CD to the place you save your file and do `python myfile.py`.

Comment: @ThePjot, well, the idea is to use std tools that come from official python website. i m ok with other tools

Comment: @ThePjot ERJAN is more or less asking the the interactive interpreter act as a command line.  Switching to another editor will not make this happen.

Comment: ERJAN: interactive python (and IDLE) execute text entered after >>> as python code.  In the posted scenario, there is no need to restart since the `dir` and `print` statements do not change the workspace.  On the other hand, there are situations where one wants and needs to restart after the program has accessed random numbers, gotten user input with `input()`, or been affected by >>> statements.  Being able to do so by hitting F5 (the default 'run' key) without switching back to the editor window  would be nice, and I have added this to my suggestions list.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy, thank u, 'suggestion list' - means you have some impact over IDLE, python ecosystem? are you active member of some python architects?!

Comment: I am a Python core developer working mostly as the main maintainer of IDLE.